# Corrections to the Bohr energies of Hydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hydrogen

Among [fine structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure), [Hyperfine splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure) and [Lamb shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift), why Hyperfine splitting is the smallest while Fine structure is the largest?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "why". Those orders of magnitudes come out when one computes the respective corrections. Can you elaborate on what exactly your question about that is?

Answer (score 1):

Electrons and nuclei both have spin.  A spinning charged particle has a magnetic dipole moment.  When a magnetic dipole is in a magnetic field, it experiences a force.  This oversimplified description gives some brief intuition on the origin of the fine and hyperfine splittings.

Fine structure is due to the interaction of the electron's spin with the magnetic field that it 'sees' from the nucleus, as seen in its rest frame.

Hyperfine structure is due to the interaction of the magnetic dipole moment of the spinning nucleus with the magnetic field it 'sees' due to the electrons orbiting it, in its rest frame.

A spinning charged particle has as  a magnetic dipole moment, which is given by:

$$\vec{\mu}=-\mu_i \vec{S}$$
where $\vec{\mu}$ is the magnetic dipole moment and $\vec{S}$ is the spin

For an electron, $\mu_i=\frac{e}{2m_e}$, where $m_e$ is the mass of the electron.

For a nucleus, $\mu_i=\frac{e}{2m_p}$, where $m_p$ is the mass of a proton.

Since the mass of the proton is $\approx 1840 \times $ more than the mass of the electron, a spinning electron will generally have a much greater dipole moment.  The magnetic field (given by $\vec{B}=-\frac{\vec{v}\times\vec{E}}{c}$) that a spinning nucleus sees in its rest frame due to orbiting electrons is of the same order of magnitude as that seen by a spinning electron due to the orbiting nucleus in its rest frame of the electron.

The interaction energy is given by $E=-\vec{\mu}.\vec{B}$.  Therefore, the greater the $\mu$, the greater the splitting.

From the above arguments, it is easy to get an intuition about why hyperfine splittings are much smaller than fine splittings.  But comparing them to the Lamb shift is not so direct.  I believe that you have to properly do the maths to see how they compare.  You mentioned that hyperfine splittings are smaller than Lamb shifts.  This is not always true.  For example, see the Hydrogen energy levels section in : http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/lamb.html.